# Centos Network Manager -nmcli How to revert to previous status of network or remove properties of network?

Tags: centos, bridge, bonding, networkmanager, nmcli

I'm a newbie in network, so please understand me.

I have a bond network, but I added a bridge network to the bond as master using

> nmcli con modify bond0 master br0

but after that, I lost IP address and other setting of the bond0 network, so I want to rollback to the previous status.

How to do it?

I tried

> nmcli con modify bond0 connection.master none
> nmcli connection up bond0 
> ->Error: Connection activation failed: Can not find a master for bond0: Master connection not fo                       und or invalid 
> nmcli con modify bond0 master none 
> -> Warning: master='none' doesn't refer to any existing profile.
> nmcli con modify bond0 connection.slave-type none 
> -> Error: failed to modify connection.slave-type: 'none' not among [bond, bridge, ovs-bridge, ovs                       -port, team, vrf].

Here is my settings

> Previous

| **settings** | **#** |
| --- | --- |
| connection.id: | bond0 |
| connection.uuid: | xxx |
| connection.stable-id: | -- |
| connection.type: | bond |
| connection.interface-name: | bond0 |
| connection.autoconnect: | yes |
| connection.autoconnect-priority: | 0 |
| connection.autoconnect-retries: | -1 (default) |
| connection.multi-connect: | 0 (default) |
| connection.auth-retries: | -1 |
| connection.timestamp: | xxx |
| connection.read-only: | no |
| connection.permissions: | -- |
| connection.zone: | -- |
| connection.master: | -- |
| connection.slave-type: | -- |
| connection.autoconnect-slaves: | -1 (default) |
| connection.secondaries: | -- |
| connection.gateway-ping-timeout: | 0 |
| connection.metered: | unknown |
| connection.lldp: | default |
| connection.mdns: | -1 (default) |
| connection.llmnr: | -1 (default) |
| connection.wait-device-timeout: | -1 |
| ipv4.method: | manual |
| ipv4.dns: | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx |
| ipv4.dns-search: | example.com |
| ipv4.dns-options: | -- |
| ipv4.dns-priority: | 0 |
| ipv4.addresses: | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 |
| ipv4.gateway: | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx |
| ipv4.routes: | -- |
| ipv4.route-metric: | -1 |
| ipv4.route-table: | 0 (unspec) |
| ipv4.routing-rules: | -- |
| ipv4.ignore-auto-routes: | no |
| ipv4.ignore-auto-dns: | no |
| ipv4.dhcp-client-id: | -- |
| ipv4.dhcp-iaid: | -- |
| ipv4.dhcp-timeout: | 0 (default) |
| ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname: | yes |
| ipv4.dhcp-hostname: | -- |
| ipv4.dhcp-fqdn: | -- |
| ipv4.dhcp-hostname-flags: | 0x0 (none) |
| ipv4.never-default: | no |
| ipv4.may-fail: | yes |
| ipv4.dad-timeout: | -1 (default) |
| ipv4.dhcp-vendor-class-identifier: | -- |
| ipv4.dhcp-reject-servers: | -- |
| ipv6.method: | auto |
| ipv6.dns: | -- |
| ipv6.dns-search: | -- |
| ipv6.dns-options: | -- |
| ipv6.dns-priority: | 0 |
| ipv6.addresses: | -- |
| ipv6.gateway: | -- |
| ipv6.routes: | -- |
| ipv6.route-metric: | -1 |
| ipv6.route-table: | 0 (unspec) |
| ipv6.routing-rules: | -- |
| ipv6.ignore-auto-routes: | no |
| ipv6.ignore-auto-dns: | no |
| ipv6.never-default: | no |
| ipv6.may-fail: | yes |
| ipv6.ip6-privacy: | 0 (disabled) |
| ipv6.addr-gen-mode: | stable-privacy |
| ipv6.ra-timeout: | 0 (default) |
| ipv6.dhcp-duid: | -- |
| ipv6.dhcp-iaid: | -- |
| ipv6.dhcp-timeout: | 0 (default) |
| ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname: | yes |
| ipv6.dhcp-hostname: | -- |
| ipv6.dhcp-hostname-flags: | 0x0 (none) |
| ipv6.token: | -- |
| bond.options: | mode=802.3ad,downdelay=0,miimon=1,updelay=0 |
| proxy.method: | none |
| proxy.browser-only: | no |
| proxy.pac-url: | -- |
| proxy.pac-script: | -- |
| GENERAL.NAME: | bond0 |
| GENERAL.UUID: | xxx |
| GENERAL.DEVICES: | bond0 |
| GENERAL.IP-IFACE: | bond0 |
| GENERAL.STATE: | activated |
| GENERAL.DEFAULT: | yes |
| GENERAL.DEFAULT6: | no |
| GENERAL.SPEC-OBJECT: | -- |
| GENERAL.VPN: | no |
| GENERAL.DBUS-PATH: | /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnecti> |
| GENERAL.CON-PATH: | /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/xxx |
| GENERAL.ZONE: | -- |
| GENERAL.MASTER-PATH: | -- |
| IP4.ADDRESS[1]: | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 |
| IP4.GATEWAY: | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx |
| IP4.ROUTE[1]: | dst = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 301 |
| IP4.ROUTE[2]: | dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, mt = 301 |
| IP4.DNS[1]: | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx |
| IP4.DNS[2]: | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx |
| IP6.ADDRESS[1]: | xxx/64 |
| IP6.GATEWAY: | -- |
| IP6.ROUTE[1]: | dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 301 |

> Current

| **settings** | **#** |
| --- | --- |
| connection.id: | bond0 |
| connection.uuid: | xxx |
| connection.stable-id: | -- |
| connection.type: | bond |
| connection.interface-name: | bond0 |
| connection.autoconnect: | yes |
| connection.autoconnect-priority: | 0 |
| connection.autoconnect-retries: | -1 (default) |
| connection.multi-connect: | 0 (default) |
| connection.auth-retries: | -1 |
| connection.timestamp: | xxx |
| connection.read-only: | no |
| connection.permissions: | -- |
| connection.zone: | -- |
| connection.master: | none |
| connection.slave-type: | bridge |
| connection.autoconnect-slaves: | 1 (yes) |
| connection.secondaries: | -- |
| connection.gateway-ping-timeout: | 0 |
| connection.metered: | unknown |
| connection.lldp: | default |
| connection.mdns: | -1 (default) |
| connection.llmnr: | -1 (default) |
| connection.dns-over-tls: | -1 (default) |
| connection.wait-device-timeout: | -1 |
| bond.options: | mode=802.3ad,lacp_rate=1,miimon=100,xmit_hash_> |
| bridge-port.priority: | 32 |
| bridge-port.path-cost: | 100 |
| bridge-port.hairpin-mode: | no |
| bridge-port.vlans: | -- |
| GENERAL.NAME: | bond0 |
| GENERAL.UUID: | xxx |
| GENERAL.DEVICES: | bond0 |
| GENERAL.IP-IFACE: | bond0 |
| GENERAL.STATE: | activated |
| GENERAL.DEFAULT: | no |
| GENERAL.DEFAULT6: | no |
| GENERAL.SPEC-OBJECT: | -- |
| GENERAL.VPN: | no |
| GENERAL.DBUS-PATH: | /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnecti> |
| GENERAL.CON-PATH: | /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/xxx |
| GENERAL.ZONE: | -- |
| GENERAL.MASTER-PATH: | /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/xxx |
| IP4.GATEWAY: | -- |
| IP6.GATEWAY: | -- |